# Using strategy pattern with environment variable laravel

Tags: php, laravel, strategy-pattern

I am currently learning about design patterns and I came across strategy pattern. I understood it, but now I want to know what would be the best solution to change strategy at runtime. Is it good solution to use ENV variables?
Example:

```
interface Logger{
    public function log();
}


class SomeOtherLogger implements Logger {

public function log(){
    echo "Logging to something else";
 }
}


class FileLogger implements Logger {

public function log(){
    echo "Logging to file";
 }
}

class Main{
public function doSomething(Loggers $logger){
    $logger->log();    
 }
}

$main = new main();
$main->doSomething(new FileLogger);
```

One thing that came across my mind is to use environment variable, but I am not sure what is the best way to do it, this one doesn't seem right to me.

```
$loggingStrategy = env('LOGGING_TYPE') . 'Logger';
$main = new main();
$main->doSomething(new $loggingStrategy);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel I have a better solution. I hope it works for you:

Laravel has a `Manager` base class that you can use to implement a strategy pattern. Consider we want to great users depends on their languages.

First, let's implement our language classes:

```
namespace App\Welcome;

class English
{
    public function great()
    {
        return 'Hi!';
    }
}
```

and for German:

```
namespace App\Welcome;

class German
{
    public function great()
    {
        return 'Halo!';
    }
}
```

Now we create `Welcome` class that extends Laravel `Manager` base class:

```
namespace App;

use App\Welcome\English;
use App\Welcome\German;
use Illuminate\Support\Manager;

class Welcome extends Manager
{
    public function getDefaultDriver()
    {
        return 'english';
    }

    public function createGermanDriver()
    {
        return new German();
    }

    public function createEnglishDriver()
    {
        return new English();
    }
}
```

Now you can you can use strategy pattern and define a **default driver** for your `Welcome` class. If you want to change the driver at runtime you can use `driver` method on the `welcome` class:

```
$greater = app(Welcome::class);
return $greater->driver('german')->great();
```

Although in this way, you use Laravel `IOC container` too. But if you want to be more convenient, combine this pattern with Laravel `Facade` feature. For instance, in our example, you should only add `Facades` prefix to the welcome class `use` keyword. The final code would be like this:

```
use Facades\App\Welcome; // <-- Laravel automatically would implement facade on the welcome class
  
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Welcome::driver('german')->great();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### StrategyController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\DesignPattern\Strategy;

use App\Traits\ApiResponser;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Strategy\Sorting\SortingStrategyContext;

class StrategyController extends Controller
{
    use ApiResponser;
    public function sortingTest(Request $request)
    {
        $items = [5, 3, 2, 4, 1];

        $sortingstrategycontext = new SortingStrategyContext('quicksort');
        $sortedItems = $sortingstrategycontext->sort($items);

        return $this->set_response($sortedItems, 200,'success', ['Sorting!']);
    }
}
```

#### SortingStrategy.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Strategy\Sorting;

interface SortingStrategy
{
    public function sort(array $items): array;
}
```

#### SortingStrategyContext.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Strategy\Sorting;

use App\Strategy\Sorting\SortingStrategy;
use App\Strategy\Sorting\BubbleSortStrategy;
use App\Strategy\Sorting\QuickSortStrategy;

class SortingStrategyContext
{
    private SortingStrategy $strategy;

    public function __construct( string $sortingStrategy )
    {
        switch ($sortingStrategy) {
            case 'bubblesort':
                $this->strategy = new BubbleSortStrategy();
                break;
            case 'quicksort':
                $this->strategy = new QuickSortStrategy();
                break;
            default:
                $this->strategy = new QuickSortStrategy();
                break;
        }
    }

    public function sort($items)
    {
        return $this->strategy->sort($items);
    }
}
```

#### BubbleSortStrategy.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Strategy\Sorting;

use App\Strategy\Sorting\SortingStrategy;

class BubbleSortStrategy implements SortingStrategy
{
    public function sort(array $items): array
    {
        $count = count($items);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $count - $i - 1; $j++) {
                if ($items[$j] > $items[$j + 1]) {
                    $temp = $items[$j];
                    $items[$j] = $items[$j + 1];
                    $items[$j + 1] = $temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```

#### QuickSortStrategy.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Strategy\Sorting;

use App\Strategy\Sorting\SortingStrategy;

class QuickSortStrategy implements SortingStrategy
{
    public function sort(array $items): array
    {
        if (count($items) <= 1) {
            return $items;
        }

        $pivot = array_shift($items);
        $left = $right = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item < $pivot) {
                $left[] = $item;
            } else {
                $right[] = $item;
            }
        }

        return array_merge($this->sort($left), array($pivot), $this->sort($right));
    }
}
```